# ng-click stops firing when adding the $location dependency in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to run a ng-click function from my controller. When I am not using the $location dependency it fires the ng-click function. As soon as this is added to the controller the ng-click function does not work. There are no errors shown either.

My App

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .when('/in-the-community', {
        templateUrl: 'views/in-the-community.html',
        controller: 'CommunityCtrl'
      })
       .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      })


  });
```

My controller when the ng-click won't fire

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$location', '$scope', function ($scope, $location) {
    console.log('cheese');
    $scope.nextContent = function(element) {
        console.log($location);
        //$location.path('/' + (element.currentTarget.attributes[0].value));
    }
  }]);
```

My controller when it will fire the ng-click event

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.nextContent = function(element) {
        console.log(element.currentTarget.attributes[0].value);
        //$location.path('/' + (element.currentTarget.attributes[0].value));
    }
  });
```

My HTML markup

```
 <nav id="nav" class="nav" >
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li><button data-location="card" ng-click="nextContent($event)">Card</button></li>
          <li><button data-location="heating-oil" ng-click="nextContent($event)">Heating Oil</button></li>

        </ul>
      </nav><!--end .nav-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed up the order of the injected variables.

Try

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',  function ($scope, $location) {
    console.log('cheese');
    $scope.nextContent = function(element) {
        console.log($location);
        //$location.path('/' + (element.currentTarget.attributes[0].value));
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: Note that you can avoid this kind of mistakes by directly calling them in your function. `angular.module('MyApp').controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $location) { ... ]);` also works and prevents injection ordering mistakes.

Comment: That is correct. Be aware when you are doing minification and the variable names get replaced, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$location', '$scope', function ($scope, $location) {
```

with

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
```